# Php function parent returned

Tags: php, oop

I have 2 function that use one validator like this

```
public function store( Request $request ) {
      $validate = $this->validator( $request );
      if ( $validate->fails() ) {
            return response()->json( [ 'errors' => $validate->errors() ] );
      }
 }

public function update( Request $request, $id ) {
      $validate = $this->validator( $request, $id );

      if ( $validate->fails() ) {
            return response()->json( [ 'errors' => $validate->errors() ] );
      }
}

private function validator( Request $request, $id = "" ) {
      $validator = Validator::make( $request->all(), [
            'name'                  => 'required',
            'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' . $id,
            'password'              => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => "required",
            'role'                  => "required"
      ] );
      if ( $validate->fails() ) {
            return response()->json( [ 'errors' => $validate->errors() ] );
      }
      return $validator;
 }
```

in this if validator it return response to validator function not parent.
I want to write function validator to check and give parent return response cuz i don't want to check and return again and again

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that inherits `Request` and that validates it's input.

On the controller side, you'd only have:

```
public function store(SomeRequestValidation $request ) {
      //Do something because it has been validated in SomeRequestValidation
 }

public function update(SomeRequestValidation $request) {
      //Do something because it has been validated in SomeRequestValidation
}
```

Note: If this is Laravel, we're talking about FormRequests

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#creating-form-requests

Edit: A little example of what you can accomplish with overriding the request's functions.

```
public function authorize(Request $request)
    {
        if (/*something*/) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

public function forbiddenResponse()
    {
        return json_encode("Oh no you don't");
        //return response()->view('errors.403');
    }
```

> https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html

Comment: To create request it will return redirect to page with errors not only json return. I write this for API

Comment: Dear @Chando, I've edited my post with a link to the documentation and an example of how you can achieve what you look for. Literally, you can do whatever you want if you just search the documentation. The example above is about a forbidden response (when authorize is false). Same can be applied to what is returned whenever validation is sucessfull or not. Thanks for the downvote, take care

Comment: i'm not down your vote. Thank for post answer and comment.

Answer (score -1):

You can throw error which will give direct response and now no need to return again and again in functions,

```
throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($error, 422, $headers));
```

I think this will help you .